# Work with Ansible facts. Get interface not active

Tags: interface, ansible, ip

I need to configure an IP address for a new interface.

For this I want to get all the interfaces available on the server and find out which one is inactive.

I use the *ansible_interfaces* variable first to discover which interfaces exist. It depends on the existing interfaces (example: **eth0** and **lo**), I will have access to the information with **ansible_eth0** and **ansible_lo**

What I need to do later is to see the **"active"** parameter for each of its interfaces, so get the name of the interface that has that parameter to **"false"** and then use it to modify a file.

Example:
A server has 3 interfaces **ens3** **ens7** and **lo**. **ens7** is incativa and I will use it to configure a new IP address. What I want is to obtain and save in a variable this value **ens7** for later use.

How can I do this with Ansible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/768470/how-to-enumerate-network-interfaces-in-ansible) as reference, you can do the following task:

```
  - set_fact:
      ansible_eth: "{% set ansible_eth = ansible_eth|default([]) + [hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_' + item]] %}{{ ansible_eth|list }}"
    when: hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_' + item]['type'] == 'ether' and hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_' + item]['active'] == false
    with_items:
      - "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_interfaces'] }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "Free device: {{ item.device }}"
    with_items: "{{ ansible_eth }}"
```

This will select ether cards that are non-active.